# Does updating an app on Google Play cause the current version's internal storage data to be deleted?

Tags: android, google-play

I am about to publish my game to the google play store, and the game contains save data.

I write data like this:

```
public static void write_to_file(String filename, String data){

    try{
        FileOutputStream fos = MainActivity.current_context.openFileOutput(filename + ".txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        try{
            osw.write(data);
            osw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Log.d("DataManager", "Attempted to write to file: " + filename + ".txt" + " couldn't write.");

        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.d("DataManager","Attempted to write to file: " + filename + ".txt" + " not found!");
    }
}
```

When I uninstall the game manually on my phone, then run the app again, the data gets deleted like normal. But when I release new versions of my app, will the same thing happen? Currently my perception of downloading a new version of the app uninstalls the current version and installs the new one. But I really don't know for sure, can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your current application internal storage wont be deleted.

> Currently my perception of downloading a new version of the app
>   uninstalls the current version and installs the new one

Also no, it is not the same process. Your data it will only be deleted with an uninstall requested by user or if you code a sequence for clearing your data in your new version.

Answer (score 0):

When you update an application without first manually uninstalling it, your data on disk is preserved. You need not worry about losing the file you are writing to.

To Test this without actually publishing this, you can make 2 versions of the apk, with different build versionCode (say version 1 and version 2). Both of them could have the exact same code base, just the different versions.

Now install and play around with a version of the app 1 and ensure that the file is created.

To update this app, run the following command:

```
adb install -r /path/to/your/version2/apk
```